# JavaFX Convert TextFlow to String

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to convert a `TextFlow` to a `String` in Java.

```
TextFlow flow = new TextFlow();
Text t1 = new Text(visibility.get(attribute.getVisibility()));
Text t2 = new Text(attribute.getName());
t2.setUnderline(true);
Text t3 = new Text(" : " + attribute.getType());
flow.getChildren().addAll(t1, t2, t3);
```

this is the way I make my `TextFlow`, and I'm trying to convert it to a string with all the three `Text` items next to each other. How should I do this? `toString()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextFlow`s does not support this. You need to implement this yourself by concatenating all `text` properties of children of type `Text`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Node node : flow.getChildren()) {
    if (node instanceof Text) {
        sb.append(((Text) node).getText());
    }
}
String fullText = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This utility method might work.

```
public static String getStringFromTextFlow(TextFlow tf) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    tf.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(t -> Text.class.equals(t.getClass()))
            .forEach(t -> sb.append(((Text) t).getText()));
    return sb.toString();
}
```